# What will be best user experience if User wants to browse books curriculum Left or Top?

Tags: filter

[image: Which filter is useful top or left for education?]
I feel top filer is user-friendly for educational site purpose. Please let me know your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Left or top navigation panels are both well accepted patterns with little to choose between them. The choice is usually dictated by the relationship between the page content and the target screen size. For example, when the content needs to be wide and the screen is already quite narrow, it makes sense to use a top navigation block to avoid using up screen space required for displaying the content. But if the content is usually quiet narrow and the screen is wide then a top navigation block might leave the content looking a bit stranded so a left navigation block might make note sense.

There are, however, other things you might want to explore such as:

What happens when the relationship between the content and the screen size changes (responsive design)?

What happens to the navigation block when the page is extremely long? Does it stay in place, scroll with the screen, or collapse?

Are there likely to be further sub pages? How will the model handle a second tier of options?

The answers to these questions will inform your choice of navigation form and position.

Comment: “The choice is usually dictated by the relationship between the page content and the target screen size.” That should be so true – alas, word processors, for instance, usually have large amounts of menus and toolbars on top although they are mostly dealing with portrait pages on landscape screens.

Comment: Ah @Crissov, word processors often need that width for the user to be able to zoom in on the document thereby making use of the entire screen width.

Comment: Nah, not buying it. Many desktop monitors can fit two whole pages at 100% zoom side by side.

Comment: But what about at 200%?